# Reload routes with all workers in production with puma (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

In my app I have a custom_page model that works just like in any other cms. An admin/moderator can create a custom page edit the content with a text editor and assign a slug.
In the custom page model I have this:

```
after_create do
    Rails.application.reload_routes!
end
```

In the routes I have this:

```
  CustomPage.where.not(slug: nil).all.each do |page|
    get "/#{page.slug}", controller: "custom_pages", action: "show", id: page.id
  end
```

It works fine in development environement but as you might expect in production with puma there's only one process/thread (I have no idea which/how) that reloads the routes. Do you guys have any idea how I can reload the routes in all processes ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I used wildcards to fix this (reloading routes wasn't a pretty solution anyway), so my routes look like this now:

```
get "/*slug", to: "custom_pages#show"
```

and in my custom_page controller:

```
before_action :get_page

def get_page
   @page = CustomPage.friendly.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
end
```

This is much better

Comment: Just watch out with the order in which you declare your routes. That wildcard is greedy and will swallow any following routes with only one `/`.